# How do I format a number of arbitrary length?

Tags: postgresql

If I have data that includes a numeric column with values into the miillions (eg `63254830038`), and I want to format the number as a US Dollar amount (eg. `$63,254,830,038`), I know I can use:

```
SELECT numeric_column, to_char(numeric_column, '$999G999G999G999') from table
```

to format the values, but to do so reliably I either have to include an unnecessarily  long text string ('$999G999G999G999') or know the maximum number of possible digits. Is there a way to say, broadly, "group numbers with a comma" instead of explicitly saying "group the hundreds, group the thousands, Oh! and please group the millions"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need cast `integer` to `money` type.

E.g.:

```
tests=> select cast(63254830038 as money);
```

Or alternative syntax:

```
tests=> select 6323254830038::money;
```

And output (I'm from Poland, so `money` type take my locales and set correct currency symbol):

```
        money         
----------------------
 63.254.830.038,00 zł
```

[`Monetary Types`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-money.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (works in sql-server, not sure about postgresql)

select convert(varchar,cast('63254830038' as money),1)

Comment: Works for me if you use `cast(... as varchar)` instead of `convert`: `$63,254,830,038.00`

Answer (score 0):

You could do things the hard way using regular expressions: convert the number into a string, reverse it, use `regexp_replace` to insert commas between pairs of 3 digits, and then reverse it again:

```
select '$' || reverse(regexp_replace(
                reverse(numeric_column::varchar),
                E'(\\d\\d\\d)(?=\\d)', '\1,', 'g'))
```

### Explanation

The first argument to `regexp_replace` is the expression to match, which contains two parts:

- `(\\d\\d\\d)` means 3 digits, which are captured
- `(?=\\d)` is a positive lookahead constraint of a single digit, meaning the match only counts if there is a digit following it. (That is, this digit is checked to exist, but it does not count as part of the match.)

The second argument is what to replace with: the 3 captured digits, plus a comma.

The third argument `'g'` is a flag indicating that it should match and replace as many times as possible.

For more information on regular expressions in PostgreSQL, see [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP).